# How to select an item that matches all attributes in a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have a table (Areas) that contains a list of areas.

```
**Area**
Area 1
Area 2
Area 3
```

Then, I have another table (People) with a list of names and areas.

```
**PersonName**     **Area**
Bob                Area 1
Dylan              Area 4
Jimi               Area 6
Hendrix            Area 2
Bob                Area 3
Bob                Area 2
Jimi               Area 3
```

I want to find all names that have ALL areas in the Areas table associated with them. So for the example data above, I would get the output Bob.

My current query returns the names of people that teach ANY of the areas in the Areas table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonName
FROM People, Areas
WHERE Areas.Area = People.Area
```

Which returns Bob, Hendrix, Jimi

How can I change this to select only Bob, who has all three areas associated with him?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Assuming that all the areas in the `People` table are valid:

```
select p.personname
from people p
group by p.personname
having count(distinct area) = (select count(distinct area) from areas);
```

If you know there are no duplicate areas for a person and no duplicates in `areas`, then you can replace the `count(distinct)` with `count()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This didn't work for me, however. It returned a list of all persons with the exact same number of areas, as the number of areas in the Areas table, but did not check if they were all equal.

Comment: @Duffluc . . . Are you saying that there are areas in the `people` table that are not in `areas`?